# Nextjs inbuilt Images are overlapping?

Tags: javascript, css, css-position, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

hey i used normal `<img>` and **Nextjs** **`<Image>`** , I am using a header with tailwind CSS  `className=" fixed left-0 right-0 top-0 "`

after using these, only the Nextjs `<Image>` is overlapping on top of my header , I had one normal `<img>` and it is working fine , but the Nextjs `<Image>` is overlapping  and also I tried to give `className="-z-10"` to `<Image>` it is working fine for the visual look , I used Link for the blog post which the image was present and I had signin button in header , when we scroll and if both blog post and signin is at same place , the Link router is triggering but the signin authentication button , can anyone help me in this ?

git link -- [git hub link of the web app](https://github.com/18121A05L2/Medium-Nextjs-clone)

deployed link -- [deployed web app](https://medium-nextjs-clone.vercel.app)

Comment: Can you share the full code of the component? Make an edit on this post

Comment: my files actually had more code , wait i will send u the git link and the deployed website link

Comment: git hub link -- https://github.com/18121A05L2/Medium-Nextjs-clone           deployed-link -- https://medium-nextjs-clone.vercel.app/

Comment: What do you mean with overlap, I see nothing wrong with Next `Image` ? Ain't this how it should look: https://i.gyazo.com/4fd69ef3b704dda09409ccdff7a43e7a.png - Also hide your firebase info in env.local so it don't get pushed to Github

Comment: scroll down bro , then u will see ovelapping of images with header

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to fix that, but what I would do is create a Layout.
Create a folder in root directory: Layout > ClientLayout.js

This goes to ClientLayout.js

```
const ClientLayout = ({ children }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div>{children}</div>
      {/* <Footer /> */}
      {/* All Modals goes below this */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ClientLayout;
```

Then go to _app.js and add this:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ClientLayout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ClientLayout>
  );
}
```